# Find column headers that match entered criteria; copy row data when all of those found columns contain value "yes"

Tags: excel, vba, lookup, index-match

Need to accomplish below but having issues with code. Included screenshots of data file.

1. Based on criteria set entered in destination sheet (Football, Baseball, Toyota, Detroit), find column headers in source sheet that match these criteria (accepts 1-6 selections)
2. Search down all columns where header names match entered criteria
3. For any row that contains yes in all of the columns where headers match entered criteria, Copy/paste row values from columns C, D, and E of source sheet to destination sheet E14:G (Name, Date, Description).
4. In this example, only two rows have a yes in all columns that match 4 entered criteria. The associated two rows values were copied to Destination sheet E14

**Destination Sheet**

[destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCDpg.jpg)

*Data source sheet**

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBw2e.jpg)

**Criteria sheet**

[criteria sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICRBK.jpg)

**Edited code per Karma

```
 Sub test() 

 Dim crit As Range: Dim cell As Range: Dim c As Range

 With Sheets("Criteria")
 Set crit = .Range("B3,C3,B6,C6,B9,C9")
 End With

 With Sheets("Source")
 For Each cell In crit.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set c = .Cells.Find(cell.Value)
        If Range(Split(c.Address, "$")(1) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) <> 
 c.Value Then
            .Range("B6").AutoFilter Field:=c.Column - 1, 
 Criteria1:="=yes", Operator:=xlAnd
        Else
            MsgBox "no match": Exit Sub
        End If
 Next
 .Range("C7", .Range("C" & 
 Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0,2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Destination").Range("E14")
 .ShowAllData
 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: You say `In this example`.  What example?  Also please include your attempt to code this as it will help us understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,

```
Sub test()
Dim crit As Range: Dim cell As Range: Dim c As Range

With Sheets("Destination")
    .Range("E14:G100000").ClearContents
End With

With Sheets("Criteria")
    Set crit = .Range("B3,C3,B6,C6,B9,C9")
End With

With Sheets("Source")
    For Each cell In crit.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Set c = .Rows(6).Find(cell.Value)
            If Range(Split(c.Address, "$")(1) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) <> c.Value Then
                .Range("C6").AutoFilter Field:=c.Column - 2, Criteria1:="=yes", Operator:=xlAnd
            Else
                MsgBox "no match": Exit Sub
            End If
    Next
    .Range("C7", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Destination").Range("E14")
    .ShowAllData
End With

End Sub
```

The process:
In sheet Destination, first it clear cell E12 to G100000
then in sheet Criteria it create a range of the criteria value into crit variable.

Then it loop to each cell which has value in crit variable
get the cell in sheet Source row 6 which has the same criteria value into variable c
if the column of c variable  has no data then it exit the sub 
if the column of c variable has data then it filter this column.

After the loop done, it copy the visible cell of the filtered area in column C to E and paste it to sheet Destination cell E14, then show all the data in sheet Source.

---

To have each name will be put to different row same column, there are two ways to do that. (A) before it write to the Destination sheet, it will ask the user to type what cell the user want to put the looped name. (B) Provide the information in (for example) sheet Criteria, such as cell E2 value = John, cell F2 value = E14 ... cell E3 value = Mike, cell F3 value = E320 ... cell E4 value = Dave, cell F4 value = E1500, and so on until all the unique name in sheet Source is assigned a cell address in column F Sheet Criteria.

Below is using point-B and it's not tested:

So after the loop done, you don't directly copy the result to the Destination sheet, but make a variable of the result first, something like 
`dim rgResult as range`
`set rgResult = .Range("C7", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

and also make a variable cnt:
`dim cnt as long:cnt=1`

Then you loop to the row value of the first column of the rgResult.
`for each cell in rgResult.columns(1).cells`

The looped cell value will be the name of the person. (say, it's John)
Then you find this name in sheet Criteria column E and get the cell address in column F
`cellAddress = sheets("Criteria").range("E:E").find(cell.value).offset(0,1).value`
So in this case "John", his cellAddress value is "E14".

Then you write it to the destination sheet:
`sheets("Destination").Range(cellAddress).Resize(1, rgResult.Columns.Count).Value = rg.Rows(cnt).Cells.Value`

then add the cnt variable for the next row of the rgResult:
`cnt = cnt+1`

then go to the next loop in the rgResult: 
`next`

FYI, the sub assumed that the macro will be run only once which is just to see what is the result of the criteria filled by the user. The sub also assumed that there will never be a result where the name show more than once. If it's more than once (say, after the first iteration the looped cell in rgResult is John then it write the result to cell E14 sheet Destination) ... then the next iteration if it's John again, it will overwrite the previous result in E14.

Comment: Thanks Karma! I have tried your code and made some edits above. I think it is very close but when changing my formatting a bit and creating a dedicated criteria sheet, it now returns only the headers from source columns C,D,E. Can you confirm its only searching row 6 of the source sheet for the criteria and not the entire sheet?

Comment: Please try `Set c = .Rows(6).Find(cell.Value)` instead of the previous code `Set c = .Cells.Find(cell.Value)`

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your sample images. Please have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: This seems to work great, thanks! Is there anyway i could introduce IF statement to say IF value in column C of source sheet is John then copy/paste associated values into destination E14, but IF it is Mike then copy/paste into E21 etc?

Comment: @DataGuy23, Please have a look on my edited answer.